# How to install chef 12 in MacOS for deployments to AWS Opsworks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I would like to know how to install chef 12 in order to deploy a Ruby on Rails app to AWS OpsWorks using a Chef 12 stack.

**Cookbook**

https://github.com/nebulab/aws-solidus-demo-opsworks_cookbook.git

$ berks install
$ berks package cookbooks.tar.gz

** AWS Opsworks Deployment Error**

```
[2020-07-03T04:21:10+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook 'deploy_resource' version '1.0.3' depends on chef version [">= 13.0"], but the running chef version is 12.18.31
[2020-07-03T04:21:10+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

**Chef Version in my MacOS local environment **

```
$ chef --version
Chef Workstation version: 20.7.81
Chef Infra Client version: 16.2.73
Chef InSpec version: 4.21.1
Chef CLI version: 3.0.11
Test Kitchen version: 2.5.2
Cookstyle version: 6.9.0

$ chef-client -version                    
Chef: 12.18.31
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. The `deploy` resource was removed from chef 14 core and extracted into a cookbook called `deploy_resource`.
2. The latest version of that cookbook requires Chef 13+ (read the error).
3. Chef 12 still came with the build in `deploy` resources.

IMHO: Either you upgrade chef or downgrade the cookbook to an older version.

Keep in mind that Chef 12 is EOL long time ago. I'm not sure how OpsWorks deals with that but I would suggest to upgrade to the latest Chef 16 (or to cinc.sh , the community build)

Comment: Thanks, Since Chef 12 is EOL, I will abandon this task, and perhaps wait until AWS OpsWorks provides support for a recent version of Chef.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OpsWorks supports Chef 13/14. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/welcome_opscm.html "The minimum supported version of chef-client on nodes associated with an AWS OpsWorks for Chef Automate server is 13.x. We recommend running at least 14.10.9, or the most current, stable chef-client version."

Comment: AWS OpsWorks Stacks currently supports Chef versions 12, 11.10, 11.4 and 0.9 
Decided to use 11.10 until a better upgrade is available. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-chef11.html

Comment: @ipegasus you are linking to the old page that is specifically made for chef 11. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/welcome_opscm.html